# OkHttp trusting certificate

Tags: android, ssl, https, keystore, okhttp

In my android app I need to execute some request to my server with OkHttp library.
I have a ssl certificate that consist in four parts:

- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
- COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
- www_mydomain_com.crt

I have imported all parts in portecle 1.9, then I set my keystore password and  I have exported the .bks cert.

Then I have inserted this mycert.bks in res/raw folder of my app project.
Now I'm trying to connect to my server by https with this code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        try{
            client.setSslSocketFactory(getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(context));
            RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                    .add("params", "xxx")
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https:\\mydomain.com")
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            return response.body().string();;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }


private SSLSocketFactory getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(Context context) {
    try {
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mycert);
        trusted.load(in, "mypass".toCharArray());
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
        TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trusted);
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyApp", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I obtain an exception, this is the logcat:

```
10-11 18:22:51.930 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname myserver.net not verified:
10-11 18:22:51.930 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     certificate: sha1/"mysha1string"
10-11 18:22:51.930 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     DN: CN=www.aaa.it,OU=PositiveSSL,OU=Domain Control Validated
10-11 18:22:51.930 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     subjectAltNames: [www.aaa.it, aaa.it]
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:244)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.aaa.android.client.Login$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(Login.java:294)
10-11 18:22:51.940 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at com.aaa.android.client.Login$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(Login.java:277)
10-11 18:22:51.950 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-11 18:22:51.950 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-11 18:22:51.950 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-11 18:22:51.950 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-11 18:22:51.950 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-11 18:22:51.950 13604-5341/com.aaa.android.client W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Where is the problem?

**UPDATE:**
I have done a lot of tries on this library and I discovered this:

- If I do a request to https:\link.com OkHttp library automatically
  trust all certificate.
- If I want trust only my certificate, I have to do the solution that I
  posted above.
- If I doesn't want to accept all host,but without use my certificate I
  can use hostnameVerifier as BNK suggest.

But why I posted the question if my solution works? Because I'm stupid and I did the request to my vps url (vpsxxx.net/directory.php) and not to my domain (mydomain.it/directory.php).

Obviously the SSL certificate is applied to my domain and not to my vps.

I'll hope that this can be useful for someone.

P.S.: Sorry for my English! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume your server app is hosting inside a server machine which has a server certificate in which `"Issued to"` is `"localhost"`, for example. Then, inside `verify` method you can verify `"localhost"`.

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        HostnameVerifier hv =
            HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
        return hv.verify("localhost", session);
    }
};
```

You can read more at the following links:

1. [HostnameVerifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html)

   > It is to be used during a handshake if the URL's hostname does not match the peer's identification hostname.
2. [Common Problems with Hostname Verification](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs)

   > One reason this can happen is due to a server configuration error. The
   >   server is configured with a certificate that does not have a subject
   >   or subject alternative name fields that match the server you are
   >   trying to reach...

Then, you can use the hostname verifier in your app, by calling `client.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);`. Hope this helps!

*P/S: another temporary workaround is `return true;` inside `verify` method, however, it's not recommended.*

Comment: Why not just return **true** in `verify()`?