# How to set SSL false and access token while consuming REST web service?

Tags: java, rest, http, https

I want to consume a GET REST web service from java. It is an HTTPS connection.
From postman, I can set the access token and SSL verification false. But if I want to do the same thing from a java class, how can I do that?

1. How to make SSL verification false in java?
2. How to set the access token in java while making calls to a REST web service?

I am using the below code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://apigateway.demo.int/demo/application/content");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
```

Comment: @user16320675 Could you provide me the site please

Comment: this one should give you some ideas https://stackoverflow.com/a/33104839/1338732
there are also other code snippets here @ SO - just use the search box

Comment: regarding question 2 - access token - they are usually passed via header field, but there are different types and conventions - some information can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-url-connection

Comment: just a side-note: I prefer using [Java's HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html)