# how to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname .com not verified:

Tags: android, okhttp

I am having the following error `Hostname domain.com not verified:` Not `"javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated"` I was able before to connect to different host, in this host I am facing problems , how to fix it

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname domain.com not verified:
    certificate: sha1//WQM9QbrKs6DCFa9qN/EIw1ywBw=
    DN: CN=*.ipage.com,OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R),OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)14,OU=GT29505539
    subjectAltNames: [*.ipage.com, ipage.com]
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:244)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
```

this is my code

```
  try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.accumulate("name", name);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("password", pass);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("email", emails);
                    json = jsonObject.toString();
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "getjson");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                }
                try{
                    RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                            .add("name", name)
                            .build();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url("https://justedhak.com/Files/users.php")
                            .post(formBody)
                            .build();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Making Https Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622004/android-making-https-request)

Comment: I guess you have not installed SSL Certificate on your server. If that is the case try just http instead of https

Comment: @denis_lor no no in the url is different error ,  'peer not authenticated"  my error is host name not verrified . btw I was able to connect to different host, in this host I am having this error.

Comment: @deepu513 I contacted the support of the host , they kept me waiting and waiting. so its problem in the host side ? and i didnt understand your example of yoururl.com

Comment: @Moudiz have you also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917988/okhttp-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-hostname-domain-com-not-verifie

Comment: I edited the comment, actually StackOverflow was converting it to link, now you can see clearly

Comment: @denis_lor he was trying to create a certificate from the first place. in my case I dont know to create one , I just want to connect to host

Comment: @deepu513 ok ill try with http  but if I want to connect with https , how to do that ? should I contact the host to install SSl certificate ?

Comment: @Moudiz do it with http, maybe https is not available on server side

Comment: @Moudiz Yes, you have to contact the host.

Comment: @deepu513 ah okay ill do that now thank you so much

Comment: @deepu513 lets say that the SSL certificat is not installed , why then I can open the link in such way https://justedhak.com/Files/users.php , do you have any idea ?

Comment: Nope in my case it didn't work, it gave me this error https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-eXLGaR38bbTG5DSmVqUlNJdFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @deepu513 ah the image will be helfpfull ill send it to the support now , I chating with them. thanks man , post what you said in an answer to accept it , you were helpful

Comment: let it be i am too lazy to write the whole answer again :P Glad i was helpful to you :)

Comment: Pls read my answer at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067368/okhttp-trusting-certificate/33071430#33071430

Comment: I really appreciat that your helping me in all my questions , my problem was I didnt purchase the certificate from the host. so I am accessing the php files such way `http` in the future maybe ill use SSL @BNK

Comment: Pls read my answer, I think you don't have to buy cert :)

Comment: @BNK hey man how are you today, can you help me in this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593342/image-not-saving-in-folder

Comment: It's Sunday night and I have no environment to test, however, in your question, the man who currently helps you is an experienced member in S.O :)

Comment: @BNK yes he is however still my problem wasent solve :( .. anyway good night my friend ill try to ry to figure it out

Comment: If your issue will not be solved tomorrow, I will try :)

Comment: Read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577810/how-to-display-image-taken-in-a-new-activity/33577998#33577998, which will have my another answer to see if it's helpful for your new issue or not. Goodluck!

Comment: I checked you answer, it deosnt manage bitmaps anyway thanks , til tomorow then

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Because the exception is `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname justedhak.com not verified` with `DN: CN=*.ipage.com...` and `subjectAltNames: [*.ipage.com, ipage.com]`

As a result, you can replace the `setHostnameVerifier` at my below sample code (because `return true` is not recommended) by the following:

```
client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                //return true;
                HostnameVerifier hv =
                        HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                return hv.verify("ipage.com", session);
            }
        });
```

You will get the success result as the below screenshot too.

---

If you want to work with that host's `HTTPS` only for your *learning* purpose or *developing* environment, you can refer the following way, of course you can change my `GET` request by your `POST` one:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://justedhak.com/Files/users.php")
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                // do something...
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                // do something...
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, response.body().string());
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's the screenshot

[image: BNK's screenshot]

You can also read more at the following question:

> [OkHttp trusting certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067368/okhttp-trusting-certificate)

Comment: IMO, you can read here http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html, at `Common Problems with Hostname Verification` section

Comment: I mean that for "return true" only, for `return hv.verify("...com", session);` I am not so sure, although you can find `caution` in Google's documentation

Comment: okay ill read about it . btw do you have an answers covers about how user login/log out session ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466653/how-to-use-security-authentication-authorization-in-asp-web-api/31471027#31471027 if it is the one you ask :)

Comment: @i-Droid I think it works, you can try `OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .hostnameVerifier(new ...)  
  .build();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(API_URL_BASE)
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
  .client(client)
  .build();`

Comment: @BNK check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445898/javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-error-in-retrieving-session-key-from-sk)

Comment: If i have multiple classes making http calls, do i need this to place everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this in retrofit2 by adding a hostname verifier and returning it to true.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                            HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                            return true;
                        }
                    })
                    .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in Jenkins trying to access GIT, the real error was that GIT address changes periodically (AWS based) and the Jenkins had an address of GIT, which was not valid anymore. A restart of jvm was enough to solve it, but reducing ttl would be best solution