# Image not saving in folder

Tags: android

I am trying to  create a folder and save images in it.
But it's not working.
I don't know what's wrong in my code - can you tell me why?

```
    // The method that invoke of uploading images
public   void openGallery() {


    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        File folder = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "albumName");


        File file = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "fileName"+3);
        Bitmap imageToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();


        Intent i = new Intent(this,
                AddImage.class);
        i.putExtra("imagePath", selectedImage.toString());
        startActivity(i);


    }
```

edit

```
        final File path =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                        (
                              //  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/ss/"
                                //Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                               Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/MyFolderName/"
                        );

        // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
        if(!path.exists())
        {
            path.mkdirs();
        }
        Bitmap imageToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        final File file = new File(path, "file" + ".jpg");
        try {
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
            final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 8192);

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            //fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
           // imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: As expert Stackoverflow user, you should be more specific than "It is not working"

Comment: @FrnankN.Stein well I am still learning about them , thanks for clarifying , i though the filename3 is the name of the image not folder.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I edit my question, I add how I modified my code but still the folder not created , can you help me with that ?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein then why the folder and the image is not created ? please note that I have add the permisions

Comment: Check out my answer. It's live code, and it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How I do make the folder in DCIM and create a file there into:

```
    /*
    Create a path where we will place our picture in the user's public
    pictures directory. Note that you should be careful about what you
    place here, since the user often manages these files.
    For pictures and other media owned by the application, consider
    Context.getExternalMediaDir().
    */
    final File path =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        (
            //Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
            //Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/MyFolderName/"
        );

    // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
    if(!path.exists())
    {
        path.mkdirs();
    }

    final File file = new File(path, fileJPG + ".jpg");

    try
    {
        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 8192);

        //bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bos);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`fileJPG` is the file name I'm creating (dynamically, adding a date).
Replace `MyFolderName` with `albumName`.
`bmp` is my Bitmap data (a screenshot, in my case).

Comment: still the folder didnt created. where I am doing wrong? the onactivityresult is working and the image that I am selecting is being upload to server.

Comment: Weird. I use this code and it's working. You already set the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission, right? By the way, it's the only one needed, since it implies the READ one too.

Comment: `  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` yeap , ill edit how I write the code maybe you can indetify a  mistake

Comment: Now you forgot to add the code which writes the file to the storage.

Comment: Yes, that one. Anyway, at least the folder should have been created.

Comment: the folder didnt created because its empty, I add the outputstream but the image wasent created , I edit my question, is it correct how I have write the outputstream ?  by the way thanks or helping me. ah ok now i saw the edit ill check it

Comment: I guess you mean: The folder HAS been created. AND it is empty. That is OK. So the folder is in place, only the file needs to be created. Now, have a look at my updated code - there's a slight difference with yours.

Comment: I got an error `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference`
on this line         `final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 8192);`, is it necessary ?

Comment: sorry the folder wasent created , I read something on SO saying that if a folder is empty it cannot be created. I tryd your code but its giving me error.

Comment: No, it's not. You can use `fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);`

Comment: Every folder is empty when it is created. THEN it's filled with something. You read something silly. If you don't want to use `Environment.DCIM`, you might want to use `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`.

Comment: the folder was created now , but the image is broken cannot be open , can you please add in your asnwer the bm how you are creating it ? it seems i am creating it wrong

Comment: It's just a screenshot (I need to give the user the ability to share a chart). It's not open from the gallery. But I'd really change this `Bitmap imageToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` to `Bitmap imageToSave = (Bitmap) data.getData();`

Comment: I dont know why the image is not created in the folder. do you recomand to open a new SO question ? .please note i added  an edit how the code is now.

Comment: when I added it I got this error             `iconvertibale types:cannot cast 'android.net.uri ' to android graphics bitmap`

Answer (score 1):

i take a long time for this faking error too and finally it's solve just with add this one line code in manifest

```
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```