# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException Error in retrieving Session key from Skyscanner API - Android

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have been working on **Sky scanner API** to retrieve the flight fares and other details in android.

I'm using the **Retrofit2** for network calls. The problem is getting error in retrieving the Session key

**Error**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname partners.api.skyscanner.net not verified:certificate: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=DN:CN=api.skyscanner.net,OU=Infrastructure,O=Skyscanner Ltd,L=London,ST=London,C=GB
```

**APIClient**

```
    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
    if (retrofit2 == null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                return hv.verify("partners.api.skyscanner.net", session);
            }
        }).build();

        retrofit2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(SKY_BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit2;
}
```

Referred SO links of SSLPeerUnverifiedException in android

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917988/okhttp-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-hostname-domain-com-not-verifie) 
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539929/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-hostname-com-not-verifie/33555404?noredirect=1#comment66213378_33555404)

Comment: Have you tried `return hv.verify("api.skyscanner.net", session);` instead?

Comment: Thanks bro. I fixed it

Comment: Ok, please read https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs, pay attention from `One reason this can happen is due to a server configuration error. The server is configured with a certificate that does not have a subject or subject alternative name fields that match the server you are trying to reach...`

Comment: @BNK I go through the article. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue with help of **BNK** Comments

1. Add **`HostnameVerifier()`** in the OkhttpClient object
2. Check the hostname before adding it in **`hv.verify(hostname, session);`**

**Fixed Code** for reference

```
 if (retrofit2 == null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                return hv.verify("api.skyscanner.net", session);
            }
        }).build();

        retrofit2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(SKY_BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a hostname verifier and returning it to true.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                            HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                            return true;
                        }
                    })
                    .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```