# Glide is not loading image hosted on s3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, android-glide

Getting below error when I try to load an image hosted on s3.

````
Glide: Load failed for https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/loremipsum.jpg with size [744x449]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException(Hostname s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com not verified:
        certificate: sha1/WxlkhkjhfslkagsflaPWk=
        DN: CN=*.facebook.com,O=Facebook\, Inc.,L=Menlo Park,ST=California,C=US
        subjectAltNames: [*.facebook.com, *.facebook.net, *.fb.com, *.fbcdn.net, *.fbsbx.com, *.messenger.com, facebook.com, fb.com, messenger.com, *.m.facebook.com, *.xx.fbcdn.net, *.xy.fbcdn.net, *.xz.fbcdn.net])
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail```
````

Comment: Below link might help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539929/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-hostname-com-not-verifie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539929/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-hostname-com-not-verifie)