# Android-server - Send password securely

Tags: php, android, symfony, security

I'm publishing my first android app and I have doubts about security with the server.

I followed the tutorial to add security in the HTTP header using sha1, everything went well.

[Tutorial](https://adrianalonso.es/desarrollo-web/web-service-security-con-symfony2-y-android/)

The problem is that the server has to know the password of the user, the client has to send it securely.

Do I have to configure the server with https for the first time the password is sent? should I always use https and forget about http headers?

Is there another secure alternative to https for secure password sending?

I am confused in these basic concepts ....

I need to introduce some security so that the url can not be used by others. It is not a user password, it is a unique string that I send to compare on the server and discard or accept future requests.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you take a look at Oauth2?

Comment: I understand that it is to give access to third parties. I do not need it, I only have one client and one server, I need to know how to register (send the password) safely. I understand that all requests have a key in the header with some encryption method, but I am interested in the first communication, in which the password is sent securely.

Comment: Do always use HTTPS.

Comment: Great narf, I did it as you tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do always use HTTPS: Narf

1 - add https to server (ubuntu 14.04, e2c Amazon), with a new unsigned certificate

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04

2 - Connect to server from android whit unsigned certificate

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned

And resolve the authorization error:

[OkHttp trusting certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067368/okhttp-trusting-certificate)

The example of Google is fine, but an image is downloaded and we are interested in making a request, I have done so:

[How to do an HTTPS POST from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504527/how-to-do-an-https-post-from-android)

To add parameters to the request:

[How to add parameters to HttpURLConnection using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post)

Works for me

Comment: Take into consideration that later on you do not want to use a self signed certificate but instead use a **real** certificate from a CA service. This way you can trust and accept the certificate without working around the authorization error.

Comment: Why would he ignore ssl certificates if he can obtain a valid certificate from  let's encrypt for free?

Comment: I need to encrypt the communication, that I get with an unsigned certificate that is free. The CA certificate costs money and my app has no web interface. I do not need it signed by a CA. I'm wrong ?